# How to use siege properly to performance test a web server?

Tags: performance-testing, siege

I am trying to use [siege](https://www.joedog.org/) for performance tests on a webpage. See also [this documentation](https://www.sitepoint.com/web-app-performance-testing-siege-plan-test-learn/).

But when I try to make an example request like

```
siege -c=1  --reps=1 https://www.google.com/search?q=42
```

I get the following output:

```
HTTP/1.1 200     0.82 secs:   24729 bytes ==> GET  /search?q=42

Transactions:                  1 hits
Availability:             100.00 %
Elapsed time:               1.82 secs
Data transferred:           0.02 MB
Response time:              0.82 secs
Transaction rate:           0.55 trans/sec
Throughput:             0.01 MB/sec
Concurrency:                0.45
Successful transactions:           1
Failed transactions:               0
Longest transaction:            0.82
Shortest transaction:           0.82
```

I thought you get the complete bunch of requests that are being made when connecting to a web site? Because when I open the inspector and go to the URL `https://www.google.com/search?q=42` I get about 20 requests coming from `google.com`, with a total of some hundred kilobytes. And with `siege` it is only one request with 24 kilobytes?

Am I doing something wrong? Do I understand the documentation incorrect?

Answer (score 0):

You have specified exactly one URL, so exactly one URL was tested. Siege is not a browser, so it is not parsing and evaluating html. You can still specify multiple URLs, e.g. via URLs file - see Siege doc: https://www.joedog.org/siege-manual/

Comment: I see. Then the documentation I am referencing is incorrect? Because in the example given in that documentation it reads: "We can see that even though we told Siege to test the URL once, 15 transactions (requests) were executed."